# Wordpress How to make a custom walllet system in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wallet

I am working on a college project which is a website in which i am buying some products from customer or user. So i want to pay them for the stuff that i buy from them.
But directly providing them cash instead i want a wallet system in which i can transfer money in their wallet so that there will be a proof of our transaction.
Is there any plugin in wordpress which can solve my above problem. Since i am new in wordpress so i don't know how to achieve this.
Please tell me that whether should i be able to achieve this type of wallet system or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So essentially you want to buy products from customers and pay them for that but without actually giving them cash.

Here are my thoughts about this and possible solutions:

1. Without a website:
   You can easily use Paypal to do this without any website and therefore you will be able to send money using your Paypal account to their Paypal account with any cash transaction (Paypal keep all records of the transaction so you can use it for finance).
2. With a website:
   You install some plugins that will turn your website into a multi vendors market Where users can sell their products directly inside your website. This solution will offer functionalities similar to famous sites like Amazon and eBay. Choosing this solution will allow your customers to sell you services or products and they get paid to their Paypal account despite the payment method you use (except cash), this way the transactions will be happening using electronic wallets which in this example PayPal and all records for transactions will be logged.

The last note is, depending on how much manual work you want to do the solutions will vary.

You may need some assistance o building such a website. Contact me if you need help.

Thanks.

Comment: Your email please?